# Failed opening required no cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Estou implementando um plugin no meu projeto no cakephp, mas quando eu faço uma requisição de um arquivo que está na pasta `'webroot/blog/file'`, ele me mostra a seguinte mensagem:

> Error: require() [http://php.net/function.require'>function.require]: Failed opening required '/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='/var/www/intercambioglobal.com.br/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')

Comment: Você esta tentando colocar um plugin de wordpress?

Comment: Isso mesmo, é um plugin de wp que puxa posts recentes.

Comment: Não irá funcionar, pois ele vai buscar as dependências do wordpress

Comment: Então, terei de montar um plugin personalizado sem usar as dependências do wordpress?
Ex: Tenho a tabela de wp_posts, então farei um plugin que trabalhe em cima dela?

Comment: Isso, você pode conectar no banco do wordpress (caso for o banco diferente da sua aplicação do cake) e fazer as consultas.

Comment: Só pra ter o conceito, o porque disso? Porque essa aplicação funciona normal se não estiver utilizando mvc?

Comment: Não é por causa do MVC, mas sim pela estrutura de pastas, o plugin do wordpress esta buscando a partir da raiz o arquivo `wp-load.php` e provavelmente vai dar diversos erros referente a outras dependências

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado.